# Running code when featherlight lightbox is open and when closed, like callback

Tags: javascript, featherlight.js

Is there a way to run code when featherlight lightbox is opened? And again when it is closed? Is there a hook or something so that I can run code after the lightbox is opened? I couldn't find examples on the github page (https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight)

**Addendum after answer from HBlackorby:**

My setup is like this: HTML:

```
<ul data-featherlight 
    data-featherlight-type="ajax" 
    data-featherlight-filter="a.box" 
    data-featherlight-before-open="MYFUNCTION">

    <li><a class="box" href="content1">Link</a></li>
    <li><a class="box" href="content2">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a class="box" href="content3">Link3</a></li>

</ul>
```

And in my seperate JavaScript-File I have the following lines of code:

```
MYFUNCTION = function(){
    console.log('Test')
}
```

Unfortunately this function is not called before opening. Also tried it with "after" instead of "before". I also don't get errors. Where do these lines of code have to be when I call featherlight in the HTML?

Comment: Are you using something like <a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
<div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>

Comment: I added the information to my question. I am calling the lightbox in the HTML.

Answer (score 6):

In your featherlight config, you can set beforeOpen, afterOpen, beforeClose, and afterClose event hooks that will call a function for you when these events happen:

https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#installation

If you are binding the box with JS, you can specify these in the config you pass to it:

`let myConfig = {
    beforeOpen:     yourFunctionName1,
    beforeContent:  yourFunctionName2,
    beforeClose:    yourFunctionName3,
    afterOpen:      yourFunctionName4
}
$('.myElement').featherlight($content, myConfig);`

Alternatively, you can also specify these events using HTML data attributes of your tag. For example:

`<img src="" id="" data-featherlight-before-open="yourFunction1()" />`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted to know. I tried now to do it like this but unfortunately my function doesn't get called. Please see my comment / addendum above.

Comment: Marc-Andre is correct, my code example is missing the () if you use the data attributes.

Answer (score 3):

`data-featherlight-before-open` must contain executable code. Try `"MYFUNCTION()"` (with parenthesis) instead of just `"MYFUNCTION"`